# What is the good DB structure to store dynamic checkbox values?

Tags: mysql, database

I have about 1 million data in `users` table.

Now I want each user can have multiple colors their like.

Example `user_id = 1` like color `blue, green, yellow, black` etc. So here what is the good database structure to store this color value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each user can have any number of colors, then you should create another table, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE userColors (
    userID INT,
    color VARCHAR(16),
    FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(user_id)
);
```

Then each user can have any number of colors, so if a user has three colors associated with them, they will have three entries in the `userColors` table.

Comment: There is no need `pk` or `fk`?

Comment: Can't use a `PRIMARY KEY` on either of these two columns because it is a many-to-many relationship, so you can and *will* have repeats of the values in each row. You could use a `FOREIGN KEY` on the `userID` field.

Answer (score 2):

From the "checkboxes" mention, I assume you have a pre-defined list of colours they can choose from, in a table along the lines of:

```
CREATE TABLE colors (
    color_id INT NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(100),
    PRIMARY KEY (color_id)
)
```

So you basically want a [Many-to-Many](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) relationship between the two, which you can express with a table like:

```
CREATE TABLE user_color_likes (
    user_id INT NOT NULL,
    color_id INT NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(user_id),
    FOREIGN KEY(color_id) REFERENCES colors(color_id)
)
```

Then if user checks boxes expressing liking for blue and red, you add two rows to that table, one mapping the user's id to the id of the color blue, the other mapping the user's id to the id of the color red.

Answer (score 0):

You Might Have a Text Consisting Colors That user Like Append each color in that Text and then Store That Text in table with type Text and at the time of retrieving use some logic to get them back,you can use StringTokenizer or Convert String into Array of String through a loop... and then from that array you can access you user's color...